# Рекурсия в хлебных крошках

Tags: php, рекурсия

Есть модель локаций, у каждой локации есть "id" и "id ее родителя" ("parent")
Необходимо получить массив родителей для вывода в цепочку для хлебных крошек от самого старшего родителя к младшему.

```
    public function location($url)
    {
        $location=Locations::firstWhere('url', $url);
        $breadcrumbs=$this->get_parent_location(NULL,$location->parent);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($breadcrumbs); // здесь я получаю только первое звено, как будто рекуррентного вызова метода нет
          echo "</pre>";
        $pois=$location->pois()->where('status','=',1)->get();
        return view('location', compact('pois','location','breadcrumbs'));
    }


    public function get_parent_location($path,$parent) {
      $loc=Locations::firstWhere('id', $parent); //полчаю инфу о родительской локации
      $path[]=array($loc->name,$loc->url); //добавляю звено в цепочку
      //далее если звено еще не страна (еще не верхний уровень) запускаю рекурсию. count($path) для перестраховки
      if ($loc->type!='country' and count($path)<10) $this->get_parent_location($path,$loc->parent);

      print_r(array_reverse($path)); //здесь я получаю нужный результат, но он не возвращается returnом
      return array_reverse($path);
    }
```

Что я полчаю print_r в public function location :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Челябинская область
            [1] => celyabinskaya_oblast
        )

)
```

Что я полчаю print_r в последней итерации public function get_parent_location:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Россия
            [1] => rossiya
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Уральский федеральный округ
            [1] => uralskii_federalnyi_okrug
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Челябинская область
            [1] => celyabinskaya_oblast
        )

)
```

то есть этот массив не возвращается returnом а возвращается ровно то же если бы рекуррентный возов функции просто закомментировать - то есть результат единственной  первой итерации

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил самостоятельно

```
    public function location($url)
    {
        $location=Locations::firstWhere('url', $url);
        $breadcrumbs=$this->get_parent_location($location->parent);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($breadcrumbs);
          echo "</pre>";

        $pois=$location->pois()->where('status','=',1)->get();
        return view('location', compact('pois','location','breadcrumbs'));
    }


    public function get_parent_location($parent) {
      static $out = [];
      $loc=Locations::firstWhere('id', $parent);
      $out[]=array($loc->name,$loc->url);
      if ($loc->type!='country' and count($out)<10) $this->get_parent_location($loc->parent);
      return array_reverse($out);
    }
```